# OpenSearch Java Client: class org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl cannot be cast to class jakarta.json.spi.JsonProvider

Tags: java, elasticsearch, jakarta-ee, elasticsearch-aggregation, opensearch

I am migrating from OpenSearch [Java High Level REST Client](https://opensearch.org/docs/2.2/clients/java-rest-high-level/) v.2.2.1 to [Java Client](https://opensearch.org/docs/2.2/clients/java/) v.2.2.1.

The logic that I am rewriting builds filters values by concurrently issuing search aggregation requests to OpenSearch. For instance, filter `Organization Name` with values `OrgA, OrgB,...., OrgN` or filter `Deadline Date` with values `2022-01-02, 2022-02-10,....`:

```
filters.parallelStream().forEach(filter -> {
            List<Object> values = openSearchService.getFilterValues(//method parameters);
            filter.setValues(values);
        });
```

After switching to OpenSearch Java client, I start getting following `ClassCastException` exception:

```
CAUSE [java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl cannot be cast to class jakarta.json.spi.JsonProvider (org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl is in unnamed module of loader 'org.glassfish.jakarta.json@1.1.6' @1a8a8f7c; jakarta.json.spi.JsonProvider is in unnamed module of loader 'deployment.my-app.war' @4543f974)]
```

Client config:

```
@Bean
public OpenSearchClient openSearchClient() {
    RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(openSearchHost, openSearchPort, "http")).build();
    OpenSearchTransport transport = new RestClientTransport(restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper());
    return new OpenSearchClient(transport);
}
```

**Note**: the fault is gone if I switch to sequential stream instead of parallel, which confuses me.

**Question**: is something wrong with the client configuration?

**App Details**: Spring based v 5.3.19, the war file is deployed to WildFly v.26.1.0.Final.

Also, I tried add explicit `jakarta.json` dependency as suggested [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/installation.html#class-not-found-jsonprovider), but that does not help.

Comment: what is type of filter var?